# Bidi associations and NHibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have classes BidiParent and BidiChildList which link parents and children in a bidirectional parent-child relationship. If a child's parent is updated by e.g. the service layer, the old and new parents' children lists are automatically updated to reflect the change. Likewise, if a parent's children list is updated by e.g. adding a new child, the child's parent is automatically changed as is the old parent's children list. I want to try to build up a "smart" domain model.

First question, obviously, is: is this even a good idea?

Second question is: is it possible to tell NHibernate to access and modify the *field* _Children or _Parent, but to consider the *property* Children or Parent to be entirely synonymous with the field? That NHibernate should load and save the internal fields, but HQL or LINQ queries should use the public properties?

```
public class BidiParent<C, P> { ... }

public class BidiChildList<C, P> : IList<C> { ... }

public class Parent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Child> Children {
        get { return ChildrenBidi; }
        set { ChildrenBidi.Set(value); }
    }
    private BidiChildList<Child, Parent> ChildrenBidi {
        get { return BidiChildList.Create(this, p => p._Children, c => c._Parent, (c, p) => c._Parent = p); }
    }
    internal IList<Child> _Children = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent {
        get { return ParentBidi.Get(); }
        set { ParentBidi.Set(value); }
    }
    private BidiParent<Child, Parent> ParentBidi {
        get { return BidiParent.Create(this, p => p._Children, () => _Parent, p => _Parent = p); }
    }
    internal Parent _Parent = null;
}

[Test]
public void MultilevelConstruction_Succeeds() {
    var p = new Parent {
        Name = "Bob",
        Children = new List<Child> {
            new Child { Name = "Kate" },
            new Child { Name = "Billy" }
        }
    };
    Assert.AreEqual(2, p.Children.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("Kate", p.Children[0].Name);
    Assert.AreEqual("Billy", p.Children[1].Name);
    Assert.AreSame(p, p.Children[0].Parent);
    Assert.AreSame(p, p.Children[1].Parent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: I need to use a naming strategy, as detailed in the [docs](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html). RTFM right?

```
<class name="Parent">
    <property name="Name" />
    <bag name="Children" access="field.pascalcase-underscore">
        <key />
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </bag>
</class>
<class name="Child">
    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="Parent" access="field.pascalcase-underscore" />
</class>
```

Comment: Did you ever see any drawbacks using this solution?

Comment: Sometimes I think "bugger it" allow my foreign key to be a nullable column as all of this extra plumbing is then redundant.