# S#arp Architecture: managing parent-child relationships

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, parent-child, s#arp-architecture

So with [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/), if you have a (say) `Dog` Entity which has a one-to-many relationship with a `Trick` Entity, how do you keep the collection in sync when adding objects etc?

That is, if there is a `Dog.Tricks` collection, and you want to add a new `Trick`, whats the best practice?

In general the approach with NHibernate seems to be to hide the mutable `Tricks` collection (that NHibernate binds to) and show an immutable IEnumberable one. See this question for a discussion of the technique: [Best practice for Handling NHibernate parent-child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944045/best-practice-for-handling-nhibernate-parent-child-collections). This seems like a nice tidy way to ensure that there's only one way to add tricks - via a `dog.AddTrick()` method - and keep the collections in sync.

But it seems that because S#arp uses Fluent, this approach is not so easy to implement (unless I've missed something?)

So whats the equivalent best practice for S#arp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the best practice for keeping your collections in sync in S# as well. Look at the Fluent NHibernate for mapping a private field. You would need to create a mapping override for your Dog entity. This override would say that the tricks collect is accessed by a camelcase field.

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Mapping_a_collection_that_uses_a_private_backing_field

Comment: OK. And for the `trick.Dog` property (pointing from the child back to the parent) is a `protected internal set` the best way to go? (so that it only gets set during the `dog.AddTrick()` method)

Comment: To be honest, that could go either way. I prefer to use the protected internal, but have done it both ways depending on the scenario.