# NHibernate strange behavior inside POCO's virtual method (Very simple case)

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I was coding a very simple case with 2 classes: Parent and Child.  Parent has n children, and children has 1 Parent.  I set up a bidirectional relationship between them.

I was trying to add a business rule to my parent, that rule checked for equality between the child's parent and the instance handling the call.  It returned false when it should have returned true.  So I simplified everything to get to the root of the problem.  So I tested the same equality outside the POCO and it returned true:

```
Parent parent0 = session.Load<Parent>(0);
Child child = session.Load<Child>(0);

bool externalTest = parent0 == child.Parent;
```

I then coded a method for my Parent to test the exact same thing:

```
bool internalTest = parent0.IsRelated(child);

... Parent Class code

public virtual bool IsRelated(Child child)
{
    return child.Parent == this;            
}
...
```

And it returns false...  I just don't get it.  It's the exact same code.

**More info:**

So to get more info, I modified my test:

```
Parent parent0 = session.Load<Parent>(0);
Child child = session.Load<Child>(0);

bool externalTest = parent0 == child.Parent;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("outside parent: " + externalTest);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Number of parent instances before call to IsRelated:" + Parent.NumberOfInstances);
parent0.IsRelated(child, parent0);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Number of parent instances after call to IsRelated:" + Parent.NumberOfInstances);

... Parent Class code
public virtual void IsRelated(Child child, Parent sameAsThis)
{
    bool internalTest = child.Parent == this;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside parent:" + internalTest);

    bool sameTest = sameAsThis == this;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this should equal sameAsThis:" + sameTest);

}
...
```

I passed the parent instance directly to itself and verify it was the same instance.  Well it's not, I get another instance created when I enter the IsRelatedMethod.

Here are my test results:

outside parent: True

Number of parent instances before call to IsRelated:1

inside parent:False

this should equal sameAsThis:False

Number of parent instances after call to IsRelated:2

What am I doing wrong ?

For detailed mapping files and pocos, see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253459/relationships-fixup-in-entityframework-vs-nhibernate)

Comment: Is this a proxy thing? The childs parent is a proxy instance? What happens if you change `.Load` to `.Get`?

Comment: Yes that totally did the trick.  I really thought Load was the correct method to call.  Post your comment in an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks Rippo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the proxy that Nhibernate uses to lazy load entities. In your case the child's parent is a proxy instance.

> To solve you problem simply change `.Load` to `.Get`

`.load` does not actually hit the database and populate the entity. See this [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) by Ayende for more info